# Rowwise indicator if all observations are NA

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to indicate if all observations in a given row are `NA`. For example, with the following data:

```
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  1, 2, NA,
  1, 2, 3,
  NA, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA
)
dat

# A tibble: 4 x 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2    NA
2     1     2     3
3    NA    NA    NA
4    NA    NA    NA
```

I want to create a new column (`allisna`) to indicate if all observations are NA. Note: I want to do this using `dplyr` (if needed, can use other `tidyverse` functions, not base R functions like `apply()`.

I have the following solution, but I prefer a solution that uses `rowwise()` and another `dplyr` function call inside of `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(allisna = apply(tmp, 1, function(x){
    case_when(all(is.na(x)) ~ 1,
              TRUE ~ 0)
  }))
```

The final product should be:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      x     y     z allisna
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     2    NA       0
2     1     2     3       0
3    NA    NA    NA       1
4    NA    NA    NA       1
```

Comment: `rowwise` is going to be slow. I don't know why @r2evans deleted his answer but you can use `dat %>% mutate(allisna = +(rowSums(!is.na(.)) == 0))`

Comment: @RonakShah will you explain the `+(` part for me?

Comment: @Brigadeiro - it's a shorthand way of essentially doing `as.numeric()` since `+(TRUE)` returns `1` and `+(FALSE)` returns 0. Nothing wrong with `as.numeric()` if you want to be explicit however.

Comment: Got it, thank you @thelatemail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out one solution (but am open to and will reward more!):

```r
dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(allisna = case_when(all(is.na(c_across(everything()))) ~ 1,
                             TRUE ~ 0))
```

EDIT to include @RonakShah's answer

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(allisna = as.numeric(rowSums(!is.na(.)) == 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

in base R without using `apply` you can do

```
dat$allisna <- +(rowSums(!is.na(dat)) == 0)
```